# Spring question about @ManagedResource annotation for JMX

Tags: spring, jmx, annotations

I would like to find out what the properties of the org.springframework.ManagedResource annotation do as seen in this JavaDoc.  I want to understand each param so I can set it to the proper value.  If anyone knows where to find more info, I would appreciate it.

http://static.springframework.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/jmx/export/annotation/ManagedResource.html

Answer (score 2):

Those are described in the JMX specification, at the section where the predefined attributes for MBeans, attributes, operation and descriptors are mentioned

Check section 4.5 of the document at [JMX 1.4 spec](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jmx/JMX_1_4_specification.pdf)

Comment: Agreed, this is where I found the answer to the same question a few weeks ago.